# generate Markdown from code with condition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter notebook, I want to use a python code to generate some markdown cells if some conditions are met.

I use Ipython.display.Mardown. It works fine if no conditions are given, but fails to display anything if a condition is given.

Here is a [minimal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB7MG.png)
:

In cell 1, a code that generates the expected Markdown:

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

Markdown("""
# First test
Here, Markdown is used outside a condition test \n
It works as I expect
""")
```

In cell 2, a code which generates no output cell:

```
SHOW=True

if SHOW:
    Markdown("""
    # Second test
    Here, Markdown is used inside a condition test \n
    It won't show
    """)
```

Using the Ipython.display.display function, the string shows in the output but in a raw form.

In cell 3, a code which generates an output cell but the string is not interpreted as a Markdown:

```
SHOW=True

if SHOW:
    display(Markdown("""
    # Third test
    Here, I also use the display function. \n
    It kind of helps but won't show as I expect
    """))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, Cell 2 doesn't work because the `Markdown` is not like `print` command, so it only displays when it's the last execution of the cell block.

Cell 3 doesn't work, because you have a new line at the start of your block quote. The following (corrected version of Cell 3) works for me:

```
SHOW=True

if SHOW:
    display(Markdown("""# Third test
    Here, I also use the display function. \n
    It kind of helps but won't show as I expect
    """))
```

Comment: Cool, it works if I remove _all_ the new lines, i.e. everything in a single string: display(Markdown("""# Third test \n Here, I also use the display function. \n\n It kind of helps but won't show as I expect""")